# Specifying Windows only compatibility in the R package DESCRIPTION file

Tags: r, package

I am including a binary executable with a package that I am creating.  I have specified its path in the /inst/ package subfolder using a file named BinaryFiles located in the root of the package installation.

Is it necessary to note elsewhere that it will only run under Windows (both 32 and 64 bit architectures) e.g. in the DESCRIPTION file?  (In addition to the documentation where this will be stated repeatedly!)

e.g. as:

`SystemRequirements: Windows`

or something to that effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a optional entry in `DESCRIPTION` specifying the operating system that is meant for this. So please see Section 1.1.1 of 'Writing R Extensions' for full details -- but in short, you want to use

```
OS_type=windows
```

here.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there anything else I need to be aware of when putting out a Windows only package with a binary executable therein (to be hosted on R-Forge)?  e.g. license issues? I have also coded OS checks into the functions.  I have spent lots of time with Writing R Extensions, but could have easily overlooked something important.

Comment: I think you cannot upload packages with embedded binaries to CRAN as everything needs to be buildable from source.  You can upload the package without it, still be Windows only and have a SystemRequirements telling people where to get that closed-source binary.